# Test code option in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, testing

Is it possible to execute code quick test in VS2010?

For example I would like to test code below just selecting it in code editor and execute it by passing variables?

```
 public static int GetInt(object value)
    {
        int result;
        Int32.TryParse(GetString(value), out result);
        return result;
    }
```

I know about Immediate Window but it does not always works and not all code can be tested with it.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Instead, you can copy-paste the code into [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) and execute it there.

Comment: I know there are two of such kind app and I have found them in the past. Just now can't remember their names.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by running the corresponding unit test you wrote before implementing the method. This will ensure that the implementation you just wrote conforms to the expected results you defined in the unit test.

Comment: And if you did not write an unit test before you still can add a testing project now and write one. You must not be test-driven to use unit tests. You can use them to play around and maybe that will lead you naturally to begin working test-driven...

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these tools:

- LINQPad: http://www.linqpad.net/
- Snippet Compiler: http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension for Visual Studio 2010 called Code Scrap which, according to the developer, "Adds a window for writing and executing scraps of code within Visual Studio."